# Is a line-preserving bijection on $\mathbb{R}^n$ an affine map?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

Suppose $f$ is a bijection $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n\geq2$.
If $f$ maps 1-D flat to 1-D flat, is $f$ an affine map?

Given two vectors $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}$, $c\boldsymbol{u}+(1-c)\boldsymbol{v}$ represents an 1-D flat, where $c$ is a variable scalar.
Since $f$ maps 1-D flats to 1-D flats,
$$
\forall c\in\mathbb{R}, \exists c'\in\mathbb{R},
f(c\boldsymbol{u}+(1-c)\boldsymbol{v}) = c'f(\boldsymbol{u})+(1-c')f(\boldsymbol{v})
$$
I think I can prove that $f$ is affine once I prove that $c=c'$, but I don't know how to prove $c=c'$.

Comment: I believe that's the fundamental theorem of affine geometry, about which there are other posts on this site.